# White screen for ios Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I just tried to duplicate an existing iOS project. After copying over all the files, and fixing all the errors, I am simply getting a white screen when the app launches. Any ideas? I do not have any MainWindow.xib files, nor are any xib files mentioned in my plist. Here is my launch code below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    MainMenuViewController *mainMenu = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenu];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

When i set a breakpoint in MainMenuViewController's viewDidLoad method, it hits it just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a launch image for your app?

Comment: When it hits your `viewDidLoad` breakpoint, try this: `po [[self view] recursiveDescription]`.  Does it look like the right view hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out... all of my .xib files were missing from the "Copy Bundle Resources" section of Build Phases.

Answer (score 0):

```
MainMenuViewController *mainMenu = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
```

Had you set view's frame of  mainMenu?